# Is there a way to have an XIB only use a portion of a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib, nib

Currently we have an XIB which we instantiate by doing this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        return cell
    }
```

The problem is the xib only represents the interior of the card, each card will have a different background (outside the xib )which needs to change based on scenario. Basically we need space around the xib to be customizable to have a different background image for each cell. Is there a way to still load the xib for each cell but still have space around the xib in the cell to change the background of the cell?

Comment: *"space around the xib in the cell to change the background of the cell"* -- why not layout your xib with the space already available?

Comment: because the background will change a lot but the interior card will remain the same

Comment: Can you post a couple images to clarify what you're trying to do? *"different background image for each cell"* ... It seems like you could add the "background image view" to your xib, with the "card view" inset to see the portion(s) of the background.

Comment: Why don't you make a `xib` consisting of just the interior of the cell and pop it into the cell when the cell has loaded? That is the way to repeat interface: a `xib` representing the repeated interface.